# Historical list of all DAX symbols (symbol, start_date, end_date)

Tags: index, index-data

Is the a public list of all DAX constituents over time? I was thinking of a table like:

```
symbol, start_date, end_date
```

It would be nice if I didn't have to resort to webscraping to get at least the list of current stocks.

Edit:
Maybe it wasn't clear to the quick reader and editor: I was asking for the symbols in the index, not for their prices. If you think this item is a duplicate, please prove that by telling me which of the links on the references question contains this information.

Comment: https://www.dax-indices.com/document/Resources/Guides/Historical_Index_Compositions.pdf 

It's a PDF, though.

Comment: Keep in mind that a symbol years ago miht have meant something other than what it means today.

Comment: @Alper Not really. And LMGTFY doesn't either if I may say so.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thanks. Unfortunately this list doesn't include symbols or ISINs. But this could be a start.